# BlueSky Statistics Issues about Blue Sky Open Source-x64

Tags: statistics

Good morning,
I downloaded the latest release of Blue Sky Open Source-x64 on my laptop (Windows 64 bit) but it's not able to open it.
I attach to you the screenshots about the writings on my desktop when I try to open Blue Sky.
I look forward your reply.
Thank you in advance.
Best Regards,
Luca

Answer (score 0):

Please send us all the log files from the following location:

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\BlueSky\Log

is your Windows username in the above path.

## Perform Cleanup

After sending us the logs delete the "BlueSky" folder from following location:

C:\Users\\AppData

After deleting "BlueSky" folder from the above location, try to launch the BlueSky Statistics application.